# brew upgrade Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/autocode

Tags: homebrew

When trying to upgrade homebrew packages, it gives back an error as follows:

`$ brew upgrade
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/autocode`

Trying to interact with the autocode package shows that there isn't such a package:

`$ brew uninstall autocode
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/autocode`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autocode` is the new name of the `crystal` formula. Instead of uninstalling and reinstalling the formula you can use `brew migrate crystal` which will move `/usr/local/Cellar/crystal` to `/usr/local/Cellar/autocode` and take care of everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Autocode is the current name of a formula that was previously called Crystal.  The Homebrew formula was renamed October 2015.  This error is likely showing up because crystal is installed.

It can be fixed with `brew uninstall crystal`.  If Autocode is a dependency of something you use, the newer version can be installed with `brew install autocode`.